# Django Server Killed

Tags: django, django-admin

I am running Django 1.6 with a custom user model. The user model inherits AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin and works fine. It let's me call login() and authenticate() and when I do syncdb it creates it with no errors and will allow me to create a superuser in the command line interface.

I am trying to use the Django admin panel. I can access /admin/ fine and login and it will display the list of registered models.

I can modify all models, with the exception of "user". I can click the "user" model and see a list of users, however if I try and add a new user or edit an existing user, the request will take approximately 1 minute and then the django web server will exit with the message "Killed".

I would post some code however I have no idea what would be relevant because the error is so vague.

Is there another error log somewhere I can find out more details?

Edit:
Custom user model code:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    full_name = models.CharField("Full Name", max_length=100)
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    time_zone = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    activation_key = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='fk_user_2_country', blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email_address'
    objects = UserManager()

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name',]

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email_address

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email_address

    def activate_email(self, activation_key):
        if self.activation_key == activation_key:
            self.activation_key = None
            self.save()
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __unique__(self):
        return self.email_address

    def is_active(self):
        return self.activation_key is None
```

Comment: you could start withe the custom user model.

Comment: @vikingosegundo added the user model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the relationship to the "Location" table `location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='fk_user_2_country', blank=True, null=True)`.

This table contained 3.3 Million rows, the Django admin panel was trying to list them all and as a result was crashing.

Comment: You should try it with `DEBUG = False`; turning debug on caches database queries and this may have exhausted the server.

Comment: Thanks @BurhanKhalid. Do you think it would support 3.3Million rows? I ended up using raw_id_fields and using a search instead of listing all rows. I don't think a browser could handle 3.3 million row in a dropdown box anyway.